# Android: Sqlite database getMaximumSize() returns size in what unit?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What is the unit of the value that we get from `getMaximumSize()` method of `SQLiteDatabase` object.

The Android documentation does not contain information about the unit.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getMaximumSize%28%29

After executing that method on my Android Tablet, I got the value `4398046507008`.

If the unit is in Bit then it is equal to `549GB`
If the unit is in Byte then it is equal to `4398GB`

I checked `Storage&USB` section of `Settings` app, i find that it has only `12GB` of Internal Storage. It looks like some thing wrong.

In one of my application i want to display the total space available for storage of cached web service data and the used space.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of that method in the source code I'm looking at is this:

```
public long getMaximumSize() {
    long pageCount = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(this, "PRAGMA max_page_count;", null);
    return pageCount * getPageSize();
}
```

[getPageSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getPageSize()) returns number of bytes, by documentation, so this returns number of bytes as well.

Comment: There are a lot of inconsistencies in this, that the returned number is too large in practice, is there possibly a way to get the maximum  size limited by the restrictions of the device?

Comment: In purely pragmatic terms, the value comes from the results of the following two sqlite commads: `PRAGMA page_size` times `PRAGMA max_page_count`.  You can read about them here: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html  Now, the max you get may only be a theoretical max.  These values can change over time.  Based on this information you might not find the result of the method helpful, and that's its own issue.  You may also want to note that maybe this value is only useful if you previously called setMaximumSize().

Comment: So if this method turns out useless in practical cases, can you maybe suggest a way to achieve what I asked in my previous comment?

Comment: The restriction is going to be based on the current amount of free space on the filesystem where your database lives, and that's going to change over time.  So I don't really think you can know the actual limit ahead of time.  The question of how to determine free space on an android device has already been answered elsewhere.